# Symfony2.5 "cannot load resource after deploying on shared hosted server "

Tags: symfony

My code is working fine in localhost but when i deployed it on a **"Shared Hosted Server"** 
then its giving following error:

**Cannot load resource "@AcmeTestBundle/controller". Make sure the "AcmeTestBundle" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class.**

on server i'm able to access **config.php** but when i tried to access **app_dev.php** or **app.php**
it shows the above error message

my routing is defined in **"app/config/routing.yml"** as

```
    test:
        resource: "@AcmeTestBundle/controller"
        type: annotation
        prefix:   /
```

I cleared the cache also but nothing changed.
Am i missing something ???

Please Help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would that be a case sensitive issue? As in `@AcmeTestBundle/Controller` is different to `@AcmeTestBundle/controller`.

Comment: no its not a case sensitive issue...